# Distribution of singular values of a random matrix with columns constrained to be restrictly positive or negative.

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, probability-distributions, random-matrices, singular-values

Let $X_n$ be a $n \times n$ real matrix, and all extries expect its last column are independently sampled from an exponential distribution $exp(1)$; the entries of the last column are independently sampled from another exponential distribution $exp(\frac{1}{n-1})$ and then multiply by -1. Therefore, now we have a random matrix with column sign constraint, and the expectation of the sum of entries $\mathbb{E}[x]=0$. How will the distribution of its singular values behave? I tried to do some simulation ($n=100$) and it seems there will be two parts: one following marchenko-pastur law, and the other part is just a single spike. Is there any proof of this? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure I understand:  the histogram is constructed from the 100 singular values so that your histogram represents just a single simulation?

Comment: Yes, this is just from one $100 \times 100$ matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $n=100$ and 1,000 simulations with *Mathematica*, I get the following for the distribution of the log of the $1000n$ singular values:

```
SeedRandom[12345];
nsim = 1000;
data = {};
n = 100;
Do[
  (* Generate matrix *)
  m = Table[If[j == n, -RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1/(n - 1)], 1][[1]],
    RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1], 1][[1]]], {i, n}, {j, n}];

  (* Get singular values *)
  sv = SingularValueList[m];

  (* Add to data *)
  data = Join[data, sv],
{k, nsim}]

MinMax[data]
(* {0.0000822545, 1942.99} *)

Histogram[Log[data], "FreedmanDiaconis", "PDF", PlotRange -> {{-8, 8}, {0, 0.62}},
  Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> Style["n = " <> ToString[n], Bold, 24],
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18] &) /@ {"log(singular value)", "Probability density"}]
```

[image: Histogram of log of singular values for n=100]

For $n=100$, there appears to be two small "spikes" to the right of most of the distribution of the log of singular values.

One can use the above code to generate an animation of the changes in distribution as $n$ goes from 2 to 50 (or more):

[image: Change in distribution as n goes from 2 to 50 and back]

Comment: Thank you! Now the question becomes more intriguing!

Comment: Maybe for $n=2$ you could find the exact distribution but I doubt it's possible for $n>2$.